# Bokeh Area Plot TypeError 'Input of table-like dict must be column-oriented'

Tags: plot, charts, typeerror, bokeh

I am new to bokeh. I'm trying to plot an Area figure with the below code -

```
source_quantity = dict(
    q1=[],
    q2=[]
)

areaPlot = Area(source_quantity, title="Area Chart", legend="top_left", xlabel='time', ylabel='Quantity')
```

I don't understand why it's giving me the following stack trace -

```
ERROR:bokeh.application.application:Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.script.ScriptHandler object at 0x10854fbd0>: Input of table-like dict must be column-oriented.
File "data_source.py", line 681, in from_data:
raise TypeError('Input of table-like dict must be column-oriented.') Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/code_runner.py", line 71, in run
    exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/e22654/workspace/python/BokehDemo/Plot.py", line 70, in <module>
    areaPlot = Area(source_quantity, title="Area Chart", legend="top_left", xlabel='time', ylabel='Quantity')
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builders/area_builder.py", line 69, in Area
    return create_and_build(AreaBuilder, data, **kws)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.py", line 62, in create_and_build
    builder = builder_class(*data, **builder_kws)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.py", line 275, in __init__
    data = ChartDataSource.from_data(*args, **data_args)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/data_source.py", line 681, in from_data
    raise TypeError('Input of table-like dict must be column-oriented.')
TypeError: Input of table-like dict must be column-oriented.
```

Comment: It appears that the empty sequences in your source_quantity are causing the exception.

Comment: That did work! Silly of me! Thank you.